# Does electric current still remain a scalar quantity even while talking about electric arcs/ discharge?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, lightning

Current is said to be a scalar quantity because it's direction is determined by the direction of the wire/conductor. But in certain cases electrical currents flow through some materials which are usually considered to be non-conducting like air in the form of arcing/discharges. One good example of such a case is lightning where there is no conductor and enought free space for the lightning/discharge to happen from any point between the cloud and the earth.

In such cases the direction of the electric current is not determined by the conductor as there is enough free space for the discharge to happen. I know that current is a Pseudo-Scalar quantity, so will it be correct to say that under these cases it may act like a vector quantity ?

Answer (score 0):

Current is derived from a vectorial quantity, the arguably more fundamental *current density*. Current density describes the flow of charge in space and is thus a vector, since it has both a magnitude and direction. In general it's given by $$\mathbf{j}(\mathbf{x})=\rho(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{v}(\mathbf{x})$$ where $\rho$ is the charge density at a point $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity (of a charged particle/volume element) at that point. For more details, see the Wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_density).

The current in a wire can be derived from the current density by integrating over the wire, and I think the vector nature of it is generally omitted from calculations because the direction is completely determined by form of the wire. To consider something like lightning, one would need to account for the vector nature of current density since charges are free to move, and not confined to a wire.

Comment: Current density is a vector, not current. Please be careful.